# Test method returns PDF data with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a `Student` model w/ a `to_pdf` method which renders a PDF generated by the [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) gem.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_pdf
    StudentPdf.new(self.id).render
  end
end
```

How would I go about writing a test for this in rspec to ensure that this method returns a PDF?

Comment: Can you show code of StudentPdf render method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any PDF document starts with the special bytes sequence (called magic bytes or magic number) `%PDF` (25 50 44 46 in hexadecimal notation) to identify them.

```
require 'prawn'
Prawn::Document.new.render[0,4]
# => "%PDF"
```

So, if you just want be sure that the returned string is a PDF document and you are not concerned about its contents, you could check the result magic bytes, for example:

```
it "must be a PDF" do
  expect(Student.new.to_pdf[0,4]).to eq('%PDF')
end
```

More info about magic bytes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Format_indicator) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: Man this is a very neat solution!

Comment: To extend onto this, you may also like to use this instead: `expect(response.content_type).to eq('application/pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use those gems [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) or [pdf-inspector](https://github.com/prawnpdf/pdf-inspector) to inspect rendered file as it done in prawn [tests](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/tree/master/spec). If you just wants to check mime-type of file, use [this gem](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) to get file extension in tests.

Comment: I don't need to check the actual contents (at least not at the moment). Is there no easy way to check mime types without the use of another gem?

Answer (score 0):

I use pdf-reader gem and recipe from comments here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised?view=comments

Here is my code:
    require "spec_helper"

```
describe Report::PerformanceReviewReportPdf do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:reviews) { create(:reviews) }
  let(:pdf) { described_class.new(user, [reviews]) }

  it 'renders pdf correctly' do
    reader = PDF::Reader.new(StringIO.new(pdf.build))
    page   = Capybara.string(reader.pages.collect(&:text).join("\n"))

    page.should have_content('Something')
  end
end

Report::PerformanceReviewReportPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    ......
  end
  def build
    text 'Something'
    render
  end
end
```